# Executing a command with its arguments that is given as an argument to a Bash script

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to write a script that adds the '&' background flag to a command that I specify. In other words, instead of adding the '&' at the end, I can add a 'b' before it such as...

```
$ b studio.sh
```

I don't know how to include the arguments such as...

```
$ b convert png.png jpeg.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as always.

```
#!/bin/bash

"$@" &
```